# Scrolling is NOT working when scrolling very fast in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Am attaching a scroll event to a div element in Angular 2. Here I am doing pagination while scrolling. The problem here is that the scroll event is NOT triggered when I'm scrolling very fast. It is working fine when I scroll slowly.

This scrolling event listener is having some problem now. I did this through Hostlistner in Angular 2. It seems when I go through online sources this scrolling event has some problems.

Could anyone help to resolve this?

Angular 2 js code:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { dataModelService } from '@app/services/asset-data-view-model.service';

@Directive({
    selector: '[lazyLoading]'
})


export class assetPageLasyLoad {

constructor(private datteService: dataModelService) { }

 @ HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])onScroll(event) {

    if (event.target.offsetHeight + event.target.scrollTop == event.target.scrollHeight) {
        console.log("END REACHED... LOADING");
        return this.datteService.assetsSlowLoad();
    }

 }

}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="assets" lazyLoading>
  some code goes here
</div>
```

Comment: Never had an issue with this. Are you sure your issue doesn't come from the fact that you binded the event to the wrong container ? This happens a lot. You need to bind the event to the element that is crolled, not necessarily to your component as a whole.

Comment: If it working then what is the issue? ( I am just read title only)

Comment: @trichetriche, i bind the event the same way you mentioned

Comment: I didn't mention anything about binding, I'm telling you to check if it is bound to the right container. Move your event around and see how it works.

Comment: i did check already, it is doing the same way, i mean event is bound to the same container where i used the directive lazyloading

Comment: Bear in mind that if you scroll extremely fast, some scroll events will be ignored. This is the way it works under the hood, regardless of Angular. Test it out by doing a console.log on a scroll event, and log the position. It may start at like 1 and then skip to 100 because the next time the event was able to fire you were at position 100 since you scrolled so fast. Conversely, run the same test and scroll very slowly. It will fire more events.